# Which strategy is the most efficient for Clickers?

Tags: the-last-of-us

I'm finding Clickers to be very hard.

As far as I can see, you have a few options:

- Craft a shiv, sneak up, grab <kbd>Δ</kbd>, then shiv <kbd>Δ</kbd>.
- Enhance your melee weapon (if you're far enough), which also requires scissors and tape.

Which of these is more efficient resource wise? I'm thinking that since I have the shiv upgrade now, trying to grab and shiv would be best.

Comment: The most effective strategy i've seen is toss a brick and run like a little girl.

Comment: If you find the melee upgrade training manual, enhancing your melee weapon becomes the most efficient, as you can take out 3 enemies with one use of scissors and tape.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I try to avoid them at all cost. Just sneaking by them and kill as little as you can, if possible. That's what I've been doing and it's been effective, though maybe not as fun, but it gets the mission done. This way, you save on supplies. If I HAD to kill and fend them off, I usually use a shotgun or a handgun since I like those the best.

Comment: +1 for the Shotgun, especially if you have the balls to let them get reasonably close.

Comment: +1 for "avoid them at all cost". In my experience, there is nothing to be gained by killing them anyway. I don't think they drop much (if anything, ever). You want to save your shivs for the locked doors that require shivs to open. If you do alarm a clicker, just run away and hide. They quickly lose interest (same goes for bloaters). However, if you alarm a runner or stalker, they will hunt you relentlessly and will bring the clickers along.

Comment: Oh, if you encounter a sleeping clicker that is in your path, an arrow to the head works wonderfully without alarming anything else in the area.

Comment: +1 "arrow to the head" @nbogard never had a purpose for the arrows. Thanks! Now I do.

Comment: Never had a purpose for the arrows? I couldn't get enough of them! :)

Answer (score 3):

While [Rob Avery's suggestion of avoidance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/120507/3062) is a valid one, I usually took it as a challenge to kill all of the enemies in an area before moving on, so I needed different tactics. I was also stingy with my shivs so barely ever used them other than as a rarely used emergency escape from clickers (with the skill) or to open doors that required shivs, so stabbing them all in the neck was out for me.

I found arrows to be really effective instead, at least on the unaware clickers. Most of the clickers you face throughout the game are easy to get close to without raising an alert, and it's usually trivial to get close enough to plop an arrow into their face, which is a nice, silent instant-kill. Just save your arrows for this purpose... they're overkill for humans, which you can just strangle, or runners, which are usually easy to melee unless they swarm you (at which point, you aren't going to want to use a bow and arrow anyway). As a bonus, you'll sometimes be able to recover the arrow after the kill.

During those occasional times when the clickers are aware of you and charging endlessly, the shotgun (if you wait until they get very close) or the rifle worked best. On hard, the rifle was often a one-shot kill even if you don't hit the head, and upgrading its ammo capacity was a big help if you needed to take out 2 or 3 in a row.

Lastly, while it costs 75 drugs (or whatever it is you buy skills with), the skill that lets you get a clicker off of you with a shiv can be a really big help. I recommend that if you plan to get it you get it as soon as possible in the game though, because it seemed to me that close-quarters fighting with clickers was a lot more common in the early and mid game than the end game. Given that without the skill a clicker's touch usually means death, it's nice to have on some of the tougher fights, particularly if you're playing on a harder difficulty where ammo is scarce.

Comment: I found the bow quite effective against people, especially if you can hit someone in the open as it will lure others to the spot so you can take them out easily.

Comment: Ageed it is effective against humans. But usually I could sneak up on them and strangle them almost as easily, making me save arrows for the clickers. Though I wish I'd had a few arrows left for the humans in the very last section of the game... About the only time found humans to be challenging.

Answer (score 2):

Though you have to get close, I like to use a brick as a melee weapon.  Using a shiv, pistol/long gun, pipe/plank etc. works, but at the cost of precious supplies.  Since bricks are so ubiquitous in the game, it is an option to dispatch the Clickers and preserve those supplies for something else.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a brick to stun them and finishing them off with a melee weapon (don't need to upgrade). Prioritize your shivs for the locked doors.

I wouldn't suggest getting the shiv master skill. It's a waste of supplements as it takes up a whole shiv to get the clicker off you. Or you can bait one to a secluded place and two headshots with a pistol will finish the clicker. After the first headshot, they normally just stay still and look down so getting the second headshot wouldn't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

in the first half of the game I mostly threw a bottle and when they all ran to it then id throw a molotov  cocktail. in a confined area it easily takes out several at once without giving away your position.
but once you get past half way you learn to use the bow more effectively. I used it more than the flamethrower.

Answer (score -1):

I would either use a shiv on them or i would save my shivs for locked doors and use a upgraded melee weapon preferably a pipe or a axe (if you are far enough in the game).  you could also use the shorty pistol or a shotgun for close range.

Answer (score -1):

My strategy either use a shiv or a pipe to kill them. Also if runners are in the area take the runners out quietly. Clickers are fairly easy to kill when no runners are around.